# Отработка AJAX при выборе <select>

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Есть

```
<select name="test" class="select-test-1">
    <option value="1">Some text</option>
    <option value="2">Some text</option>
    <option value="3">Some text</option>
    <option value="4">Some text</option>
    <option value="5">Some text</option>
</select>
```

Нужно при выборе элемента, получить его value (там хранится ID поста в Wordpress) и с помощью AJAX передать его в обработчик. Код работает, но срабатывает только один раз - первый, в дальнейшем после выбора другого элемента тега `<select>` перезагрузка не происходит. Пробовал этот же код без AJAX в консоль выводится каждый раз значение при выборе другого элемента из списка, с AJAX не работает. Не сильно с ним знаком, т.ч. вполне подозреваю что сделал что-то не так.

```
$('.select-test-1').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php") ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'myajax',
            postID: selected
        },
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {},
        success: function(data) {
            $('.card-item-1').html(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> но срабатывает только один раз

Элемент `'.select-test-1'` находится внутри `'.card-item-1'`. При назначении `$('.card-item-1').html(data);` все элементы внутри `'.card-item-1'` создаются заново - а старые (со своими событиями) уничтожаются. Используйте делегирование при назначении события:

```
$(document).on('change', '.select-test-1', function() {
```

Comment: Вы Гений, спасибо :)