# Jquery onclick не срабатывает при обновлении через AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет, есть onclick event

```
$(".delete-button").click(function() {

data = [];
data['id'] = $(this).closest('div').attr('id')

Ajax.updateProductList(data);

}
```

Есть контейнер

```
<div class="product-list">
  <span id="1">Product1</span><button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
  <span id="2">Product2</span><button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
  <span id="3">Product3</span><button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Есть Функция Ajax.updateProductList(data)

```
var productId = data['id'];

$.ajax({
  headers: app.header,
  url: app.handleProductId,
  data: {
    productId: productId,
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    if(data.status == 1) {

        alert(data.status);

        console.info($('.product-list').html());

        $('.product-list').html(data.html);

        console.info(data.html);

    }
});
```

При нажатии на кнопку delete, запрос отправляется серверу, сервер удаляет из бд 1 продукт, берет список продуктов и возвращает его как html, из jquery получаем новый product-list и меняем на текущий product-list через

```
$('.product-list').html(data.html)
```

и после этого, кнопки delete-button не срабатывают, `onclick` их не отрабатываем, в чем причина ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отработка AJAX при выборе <select>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762325/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-ajax-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-select)

Comment: Не думаю, что это дубликат, но вопрос вообще непонятен чуть более чем полностью ...

Comment: постараюсь отредактирован вопрос, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: поправил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @S1lllver, все стало ещё запутаннее ... Ответ который вам дали выглядит разумно, но с вашими правками стало понятно что: для вашей кнопки `$(this).closest('div')` - `<div class="product-list">` у которого нет айди и это вообще нелогично и как это в принципе работать должно неясно. Зачем вообще передавать `data`, если используется только `id`. Зачем возвращать целый блок, вместо того, что бы удалять элемент при успешном завершении тоже не очевидно .... Попрокидывайте `console.log()` в функциях, либо на худой конец скиньте все что есть, а не кусками

Comment: поправил id, была опечатка.
Ну так вот дело в том что, новый созданный список не обрабатывается 
через onclick

Comment: все сработало, спасибо, дело было в делегировании

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete-button", function() {
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, сработало